# How to using asmack set avatar?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, ejabberd, asmack

I'm writing sample xmpp client, need to set account user avatar.

Following the sample in the ignite site, i could login to xmpp server, but cannot set useravatar, with ejabberd server side. I also try using beem (opensource xmpp project) also with asmack in the core, it cannot set avatar also.

Please help, thanks for any suggestion

```
ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());
                    VCard vCard = new VCard();
                    try {
                        vCard.load(connection);
                        vCard.setAvatar(byteArray);
                        vCard.save(connection);
                    } catch (XMPPException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: Please show us some code

Comment: @Flow i have figured out the problem thats image size too big, but now i got problem that the new avatar is not show changes in my buddy client. Got any suggestion ?

Comment: Which version of aSmack are you using?

Comment: Thanks @Flow, i found out that according to http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0153.html, have to send presence with extension contains photo hash to publish

Answer (score 1):

the problem with XEP documentation is that it only contains the message data information but not how to implement them. for example to get lastname from vCard I need to type:

```
String lastname = vCard.getlastname(); // just example
```

this information I cannot see anywhere in the xep documentation. therefore I think answers should stop asking the questioners to see the documentation since, they have already in most cases seen them but did not find the answers and so turned to SO. but if there is any documentation that shows how to implement the smack library would be useful to cite. Thank you! and Happy Programming!